# Center chart.js canvas in a container without added buffer

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to center a Chart.js bar chart where the height and width are based on the viewport.

The [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html) explicitly states that the following method does not work `<canvas style="margin: 0 auto;">`. Indeed, it makes the graph shrink continuously smaller and smaller.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"</canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

Javascript:
There is Javascript code that fetches the element and creates a `new Chart` within in. Simplified below:

```
  const element = document.getElementById('myChart');
  new Chart(element, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Alpha',
        data: [1, 2, 3]
      }]
    }
  });
```

I would like the parent container to be the same vertical size as the canvas (to avoid adding unwanted buffer in my webpage).

[You can see here that as the screen becomes too wide and the height-based sizing takes effect, the chart is shoved to the left side of the chart-container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNQuJ.png)

[You can see here that as the screen becomes too long and the width-based sizing takes effect, the chart-container pushes down the next element, creating a large space gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqr34.png)

Comment: Your approach corresponds to the recommended solution (style the sizes and position of the div containing the canvas, not the canvas itself) and it works - it centers the chart horizontally ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfgybm57/)). If you also want to center it vertically, you should just implement that with css somehow, for instance like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb4Lag5o/)

Comment: @kikon Thank you so much for putting together this fiddle and for helping me out. The problem occurs when the screen becomes so wide and the height-based viewport restriction takes over. At that point, the chart is shoved to the left of the container. I attached an image in the post. Let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix this!

Comment: Is the flex `justify-content: center;` doing the same - you can try the second fiddle and disable the `top` property if you don't care for vertical centering

Comment: Thanks. The flex is much nicer! If the window is thin, it adds extra buffer vertically pushing other elements further down the page and adding a lot of whitespace. I'm also messing around with resizing in JS via eventlistener and got a pretty good result. I will post an edit

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using some Javascript:

```
const chartContainers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('chart-container'));
const chartMaxWidthPercent = 0.9;
const chartMaxHeightPercent = 0.7;

function resizeChartContainers() {
  let maxWidth = chartMaxHeightPercent * window.innerWidth;
  let maxHeight = chartMaxHeightPercent * window.innerHeight;
  let width = Math.min(maxWidth, maxHeight * 2);
  let height = Math.min(maxHeight, maxWidth / 2);
  chartContainers.forEach(container => {
    container.style.width=`${width}px`;
    container.style.height=`${height}px`;
  });
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeChartContainers);
resizeChartContainers(); // Initial resize
```

Then in my CSS I removed the height and width specifications:

```
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```